# How to make POS scalable?

Tags: odoo, e-commerce, scalability, point-of-sale

If I want to load 10000 products without any picture or ean13 code. I am running openERP and POS on a server (4-core i7-3520M @2.90GHz - 8Go RAM); it takes the POS long time to load...

This is very long for non-technical persons whom usually expect computers to work immediately.

The system is simply not scalable :

imagine a bookstore with 300 000 products
imagine a chain of bookstores having multiple pos
imagine a big store with tens of cashier
How to make POS scalable ? Obviously I can always use a server with better configuration but what are the other alternatives like local storage, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pos_cache** module if you are using pos in odoo version 9.0

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/pos_cache/

This creates a product cache per POS config. It drastically lowers the time it takes to load a POS session with a lot of products.

Comment: apart from loading products, there are several issues like handling multiple pos by the same server....What are the ways in which I can reduce server load and still use multiple pos concurrently?

Comment: Only loading products from cache will reduce lot of time, once pos load on browser, it will work like offline even if internet is not there. so after this it will not making load on server